# Why does adding my viewcontroller to a navigationcontroller seem to interfere with my constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, constraints

As I find it difficult sometimes to get what I expect from layouting with storyboards, I am playing around a bit with programmatic constraints... I am aware that getting started here will be more difficult – but hope the „end-game“ with this approach is more efficient. ;-)

When I use the following code on a simple viewController & mainView & centerView combo everything is as expected i.e. mainView fills entire screen available and centerView fills only the center part of mainView:

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_centerView);
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"padding":@15.0};
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-padding-[_centerView]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-padding-[_centerView]-padding-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:viewsDictionary]];
```

If I add the same viewController to an navigationController as root however (or define a different VC as root and push mine on later), it does not work as expected: the screen below the navBar is now just plain white.

I colored all views and the missing ones seem to „shine through“ a bit from the top left corner under the navigation bar. Why does the navigation controller „interfere“ with the above layout constraints at all? I was under the impression that the main view of the root view controller of a navigation controller by default fills the „remainder“ of the window below the navigation bar. Or am I mistaken and need to add constraints between navigation and my mainView? Or am I missing something else?

Any ideas?

BTW.: If someone knows a good tutorial or blog or other source that deals with the issue of programmatically composing screens & navigation between them (navigation controllers, tabbar controllers, views) and/or adding layout constraints I would be also very interested.

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after some more testing, it appears that at least in my case I shouldn't set view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; for the rootView. As soon as I set it to YES (for this view only) it works again...

Comment: You don't need to set it to YES, since that's the default, just don't set it at all. You should never set this property to NO for a controller's self.view. Is "view" the controller's main view?

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks for your comment! Yes, I was referring to the self.view and yes, the default for all views with regard to that property is NO. But I have read that when programmatically (without storyboard) setting constraints you need to always always set that property to NO for your views. So I created a category and whenever I create a new view that sets it to NO. But as you indicated this seems to be wrong for self.view. (However, honestly I still don't really know why.)

Comment: Oops, I guess it's too late already: I meant to say the default to this property is YES of course, as rdelmar already stated...